# Integrating CoffeeScript with Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, coffeescript

Is there a way to integrate CoffeeScript and Eclipse, so that when I write CoffeeScript in one window the other will show the compiled code as Javascript?

I'll wait for answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

I've done it with a builder and a small shell script in my project. Every time I save a .coffee file, it compiles all my scripts. Works *great*.

Right click on your project. Select properties near the bottom of the menu.

- Builders
- New...
- Location: ${workspace_loc:/ProjectName/coffee-compile.sh}
- Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/ProjectName}
- Refresh: Specify the folder where your generated .js files live. This allows you to keep the .js file open as well and it'll auto update when things re-compile.
- Build Options: Specify the folder where your .coffee files live.

ProjectName/coffee-compile.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ./target/coffee ]; then
    mkdir -p ./target/coffee
fi

echo "Compiling coffee script files..."
/usr/bin/coffee --output ./target/coffee --compile ./coffee

echo "Done..."
```

The builder definition is saved as part of your project. It is in the .settings folder. That way, other developers can check out your project as well and have everything already set up.

Update: For code formatting and coloring, I ended up installing the latest beta of Aptana into Eclipse.

**Update2**: I've stopped using Eclipse in favor of Intellij. The editors and built in support for compiling code are wonderful. I highly suggest you try it out.

Comment: Does not work for me, I get an env: node: file not found error. Any hints?

P.s: The script gets executed properly. I see the echos output and the target/coffee folder is created too.

Comment: You need to install NodeJS and CoffeeScript first. Follow their directions for the respective projects.

Comment: I do have node and coffeescript installed. If I change the script to `node -v` it prints out the node version in eclipse's console. But the above script won't work. But if I run it in Terminal, it works...

Comment: The script references /usr/bin/coffee, not node. Coffee depends on node.

Comment: This technique also works for anyone using SASS stylesheets.  Just change the shell script coffee line to sass:  /usr/bin/sass --update /source/folder:/target/folder

Comment: You can also leave out the extra script and select /usr/bin/coffee in Location and "--output ./target/coffee --compile ./coffee" in Arguments. You have to make sure that target/coffee exists. I also had to add a PATH with /usr/local/bin (where node lives) under Environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `coffee`s `-w` option for this. Open a terminal, `cd` to your project directory and then run `coffee -w ./coffee -c ./js`. Assuming that your `coffee` files are stored in a folder named `coffee` and you are compiling your files to a folder named `js`.

Keep the terminal open while your coding session. `coffee` will compile your script every time you resave the file.

Comment: That solution works as well. I just prefer not having to remember to start up the watcher. The reason is that I can see restarting my machine or killing the watcher and then going to edit files and wondering why my changes aren't showing up. Then, facepalm'ing myself  about forgetting to start the watcher. Also, in a group environment, having an Eclipse builder works great since you only need to tell people to install coffee. Everything else just works.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin to automatically transpile CoffeeScript files (amongst others) automatically.

-> https://github.com/gossi/eclipse-transpiler-plugin

Basically, it does the same as Jon Stevens Shell script, but has a nice UI for the configuration.