# How to use CoffeeScript and Eclipse together in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, eclipse, coffeescript

I want to use CoffeeScript inside Eclipse, because I'm working on a project of a game using JavaScript and my productivity is slow... so I want to integrate CoffeeScript with Eclipse in Windows enviroment... is that possible?

Comment: This question is similar to an earlier one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6645640/399470

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are currently 3 options I know of:

1. LiClipse: http://www.liclipse.com/
2. Aptana Studio 3: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3
3. CoffeScript-Eclipse: https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse

Comment: All I wanted was syntax highlighting for the time being, and this is great!

Answer (score 2):

Syntax coloring and code completion is available in the [coffeescript-eclipse](https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse) plugin on github

Answer (score 1):

You may want to download the [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html) software. Then add this update: http://coffeescript-editor.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg/

Comment: This is the same plugin as Ryan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The same CoffeeScript Editor by Adam Schmideg and XText dependency as single install is available on [Eclipse MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/coffeescript-editor-quick-installer).